# ¿Como puedo realizar un JOIN dejando datos en NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Estuve tratando de realizar un `left join` con el objetivo de traer como resultado algo como lo siguiente:

```
ID      nombre            clave       calif
10022   Juan Alcantara    MX-RT4533       9
22587   Rodolfo Cota      NULL         NULL
10001   Pedro Rodriguez   MX-RT4534      10
10002   Julio Mata        MX-RT4535       6
10288   Wayne Doroti      MX-RT4536       5
98871   Camila Fernandez  MX-RT4534       7
```

Mi objetivo es que de mi tabla resultados me traiga todos sus datos y los que no existen traerlos de la tabla alumnos, dejando solo los registros de la primer tabla ya que en mi segunda tabla puede tener cientos de registros, bueno estas son mis dos tablas:

Resultados:

[image: Result]

Alumnos:

[image: Alunos]

Como comente, solo quiero traer el `workdayID` y nombre de mi segunda tabla a la primera, ¿Como puedo hacer esto?

Este es mi query:

```
SELECT r.clave,r.emp_clave,a.nombre,r.calif  
                FROM dbo.Resultados r 
                LEFT JOIN Alumnos a ON  a.workDayId = r.emp_clave
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Pues la respuesta es un left join, que dices que ya trataste. ¿cuál es el problema que encontraste? Creo que vendría bien añadir el código de la consulta que has intentado y explicar qué dificultad tienes.

Comment: @jachguate Listo, el problema es que no me devuelve ningun registro. Es decir, mi objetivo es que aunque no exista en la tabla resultados el id  pero si existe en la tabla alumnos que lo traiga a la tabla resultados

Comment: @jachguate ya puede resolver mi problema, igualmente muchas gracias por estar pendientes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás haciendo un `left join` pero estás poniendo la tabla (*base*) de la que quieres traer todos los registros a la derecha del join y la tabla de la que quieres traer *los que se puedan* a la izquierda.

Hay dos maneras de resolverlo:

- Cambiar el tipo de *join* de `left join` a `right join`, para indicar que la tabla base está a la derecha:

  ```
    FROM dbo.Resultados r RIGHT JOIN Alumnos a ON a.workDayId = r.emp_clave
  ```
- Cambiar el orden de las tablas y mantener la sentencia *left join*:

  ```
    FROM Alumnos a LEFT JOIN dbo.Resultados r ON a.workDayId = r.emp_clave
  ```

He escrito toda la sentencia en una sola línea para que quede más claro qué está a la izquierda (left) y qué está a la derecha (right) en cada caso.

Como era de esperar la *dirección* del *join* es importante. Recuerda en el futuro que debes tener claro cuál es la tabla (o join de tablas) **base**, que es aquella de la que el resultado va a tomar todos los registros, y cuál es la tabla de la que se tomarán los registros que existan, rellenando con `null` las filas para las que no haya registro.

Si la tabla o join de tablas base está a la **izquierda** de la tabla destino, entonces usa **`left join`** y si está a la **derecha** usa **`right join`**.